# How to effectively transfer a two-dimensional list data to list of dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```py
key_list = ['a', 'b']
value_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4],...]
res = [dict(zip(key_list, item)) for item in value_list]
print(res)   # [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, ...]
```

code as above can get what I want (list of dict element): `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}, ...]`
but I think this maybe not effective way.
Is there some more effective method to transfer?

Comment: "but i think this maybe not effective way". Why do you think so?

Comment: coz the length of value_list can be very large, maybe 10million level. And key_list has more than 10 keys. so with this for loop will consume lot of time.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you will use `res` for, but you can have generator, instead of list if it suits your needs

Comment: How will you use a List of around 10million Dictionaries? As @buran implies a generator rather than your comprehension would give sequential access to these without forming the whole List beforehand so saving time and reducing memory used. Hence the final use determines the best approach.

Comment: I can't think of a more straight-forward way than what you did. Regarding efficiency, each sublist in `value_list` represents a dict to be created, so you will ***have to*** iterate over all of those sublists one way or another...

Comment: You could look into using numba for optimising. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to iterate through `res` sequentially and it is made from huge lists you could use:

```
res = (dict(zip(key_list, item)) for item in value_list)
```

(Note the round parenthesis), this will create the pairs one by one as you request them. Keep in mind that with this way you will only be able to iterate over `res` once and you will not be able to index it.